# enable twig's debug in production

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using Symfony's debug bundle:

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(), 
    ...
    new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle()
```

);

Temporarily, I would like to enable the dump() method in my production environment (and is configured to work like that in AppKernel.php).

Unfortunately the dump is not outputting anything, unlike in dev mode. Do I always need to set the dump_destination parameter if I want to enable it in production?

Answer (score 2):

Add in the `config_prod.yml` files the line (or simply add the debug key if you have other configuration in the ):

**config_prod.yml**

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
```